# Are servlets the only way to write a Java Web Application

Tags: java, servlets

Are servlets the only way one can write web applications in Java ?

Comment: +1 Sounds like a valid question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. [Servlets](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/) are just the most convenient way to write a Web application in Java. If you think about it: what is a Web application? Quite simply it is an application that can receive an HTTP request and send back an HTTP response. Common models for achieving this are:

1. To use some kind of wrapper that invokes a script for each request. This was the first model and has a standard called [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (Common Gateway Interface). The wrapper in this case is a Web server; or
2. To have persistent code within such a wrapper that can service HTTP requests (rather than being transient like CGI scripts).

There are variations upon this theme (eg [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) for (1)). Servlets are an example of (2). The reason 99% of all Java Web applications and frameworks use servlets is because servlets are standard (they have a specification endorsed by Sun and a [reference implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/)) and they're so low-level that pretty much whatever you want can be built on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

That servlets are most convenient way to write Web apps in Java is arguable. They certainly have been around for a long time, but there are alternatives; take a look at restlets for example:  http://www.restlet.org/

Comment: They're built **on top** of the Servlet API and it again boils down to the question: "are servlets the only way?".

Comment: Oh I hadn't heard about restlet until you mentioned

Comment: There is a brief restlet summary here: http://www.restlet.org/about/introduction . The original implementation was indeed "on top". The current one is not.